# android passing Location method to another class // nullpointexception

Tags: android, geolocation

I am writing a custom app, and I want to separate the different functions in it like different classes, for better code maintenance.

Currently, I have the class `MainActivity` and the class `GPSLoc`; there is a button in `MainActivity` which should show the latitude and longitude by invoking a method from Class `GPSLoc`, but unfortunately, as soon as I hit the button, it throws `NullPointException`, here is the `GPSLoc` class, and I've tested the methods standalone and it works fine.

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
    GPSLoc Test1=new GPSLoc();
    Test1.showCoordinate();
    }
});
```

here is also the LogCat

```
07-07 19:04:24.730: E/AndroidRuntime(830): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-07 19:04:24.730: E/AndroidRuntime(830): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-07 19:04:24.730: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at com.example.testnewbutton.GPSLoc.showCoordinate(GPSLoc.java:122)
07-07 19:04:24.730: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at com.example.testnewbutton.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:53)
07-07 19:04:24.730: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.View.performClick   (View.java:4204)
07-07 19:04:24.730: E/AndroidRuntime(830):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
```

here is the ShowCoordinate method

```
   public void showCoordinate ()



   {

    LocationManager manager = (LocationManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

       LocationListener ll=new MyLocationListener();
       manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ll);




       Location location=manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);



       if (location != null) {
           String message = String.format(
                   "Current Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s",
                   location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude()

                   );

           {  Toast.makeText(mContext, message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}


       }









   }
```

Comment: You need to look at the stacktrace (LogCat) that is generated.  It will tell you the offending line of your code.

Comment: i was wondering if this becase GPSLoc also extends Activity, so is using Intent a must here ?

Comment: Any reason why the GPS stuff is in a different Activity to the one actually displaying the data?

Comment: i just wanted to split the code in different chunks , therefore created a separate class for the GPS

Comment: The GPS stuff can be in a class of its own but that class does not need to extend Activity.

Comment: i tried without the Activity , but still it gives nullpointexception

Comment: post `com.example.testnewbutton.GPSLoc.showCoordinate()`.  Line 122 of `GPSLoc` is the problem.

Comment: change GPS_PROVIDER to NetWork_PROVIDER

Comment: changing providers will not do anything , as i said the methot itself works perfectly , it looks like its not passed correctly

Answer (score 0):

Use bellow code.
public class LocationListenerClass

{
private static LocationListenerClass instance;

private static Context context;
    private LocationManager myLocationManager;
    private LocationListener myLocationListener;
    private static Double latitude = 0d;
    private static Double longitude = 0d;

```
public static LocationListenerClass getInstance(Context context) {
    LocationListenerClass.context = context;
    if (null == instance) {
        instance = new LocationListenerClass();
    }
    return instance;
}

public void getCurrentLocation() {
    try {
        myLocationManager = (LocationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        myLocationListener = new MyLocationListener();
        myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 30000, 100,
                myLocationListener);

        Location location;
        location = myLocationManager
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (location == null) {
            myLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 30000, 100,
                    myLocationListener);
            location = myLocationManager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        }

        if (location != null) {
            try {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                Data.CURENT_LATITUDE = latitude;
                Log.v(ConstantLib.LOG, " latitude : "
                        + Data.CURENT_LATITUDE);
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                Data.CURENT_LONGITUDE = longitude;
                Log.v(ConstantLib.LOG, " longitude : "
                        + Data.CURENT_LONGITUDE);

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

}

public void removeLocationUpdates() {
    try {
        if (myLocationManager != null) {
            myLocationManager.removeUpdates(myLocationListener);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        try {
            if (location != null) {
                Data.CURENT_LATITUDE = location.getLatitude();
                Log.v(ConstantLib.LOG, "LOCATION CHANGED" + " latitude : "
                        + Data.CURENT_LATITUDE);
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                Data.CURENT_LONGITUDE = location.getLongitude();
                Log.v(ConstantLib.LOG, "LOCATION CHANGED" + " longitude : "
                        + Data.CURENT_LONGITUDE);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

}